# Rails unit test ignores `trailing_slash: true`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing, ruby-on-rails-5

I use rails 5.0.3 and minitest 5.10.1.

In my rails application, config/application.rb has the following part:

```
config.action_controller.default_url_options = { trailing_slash: true }
```

With this setting, `reviews_path` in controller code returns `/reviews/`.

However, `app.reviews_path` in rails console or `reviews_path` in unit test code which uses `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` returns `/reviews`.

I use [`Rack::AppendTrailingSlash` middleware](https://github.com/tkellen/rack-slashenforce).

So if path helper does not handle trailing slash properly in test code,
test fails without extra `follow_redirect!`

How can I make `reviews_path` return `/reviews/` in test code?

Answer (score 0):

❌ This doesn't work in `application.rb`:

```rb
config.action_controller.default_url_options = { trailing_slash: true }
```

✅ This *does* work in `application.rb`:

```rb
routes.default_url_options[:trailing_slash] = true
```

With the configuration above, your slashes will still be there when you run your tests. Tested with Rails `7.0.4.2`.